# Binding to Static Resource via Name

Tags: wpf, windows-phone-8, binding, itemtemplate, staticresource

I get next templates:

```
<Page.Resources>
   <DataTemplate x:Key="T1">...</DataTemplate>
   <DataTemplate x:Key="T2">...</DataTemplate>
   <DataTemplate x:Key="T3">...</DataTemplate>
</Page.Resources>
```

and a list of items:

```
class SampleItem {
 ...
 public string ItemTemplateName { get; set; }
}
```

and I'm dreaming to use it in the next way:

```
<ListView
   ItemTemplate = "{StaticResource {Binding ItemTemplateName}}">
</ListView>
```

Is this possible to do something like that? And that will be the right binding for this case?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please try to use the template selector in this case.

**XAML Page resources changes**

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="T1">
        <Rectangle Fill="Tomato" Width="50" Height="50"></Rectangle>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="T2">
        <Rectangle Fill="Green" Width="50" Height="50"></Rectangle>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="T3">
        <Rectangle Fill="Blue" Width="50" Height="50"></Rectangle>
    </DataTemplate>
    <gridbackgroundProblemSoHelpAttempt:MyTemplateSelector x:Key="MyTemplateSelector" 
                                                           ADataTemplate="{StaticResource T1}"
                                                           BDataTemplate="{StaticResource T2}"
                                                           CDataTemplate="{StaticResource T3}"/>
```

**Xaml ListView changes (please note that the SampleItems is an ObservableCollection of SampleItem objects)**

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding SampleItems}" ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource MyTemplateSelector}"/>
```

**MyTemplateSelector code**

```
 public class MyTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public DataTemplate ADataTemplate { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate BDataTemplate { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate CDataTemplate { get; set; }

    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        var si = item as SampleItem;
        if (si == null) return null;
        var key = si.ItemTemplateName;

        switch (key)
        {
            case "A":
            {
                return ADataTemplate;
            }
                break;
            case "B":
            {
                return BDataTemplate;
            }
                break;
            case "C":
            {
                return CDataTemplate;
            }
                break;

            default:
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
        }

    }
}
```

**Page DataContext**

```
public class MainViewModel
{
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        SampleItems = new ObservableCollection<SampleItem>
        {
            new SampleItem{ItemTemplateName = "A"},
            new SampleItem{ItemTemplateName = "B"},
            new SampleItem{ItemTemplateName = "C"},

        };
    }
    public ObservableCollection<SampleItem> SampleItems { get; set; }
}
```

Regards,

Comment: Thank you for the answer! That's a great idea.